# 4 tikzpictures in a 2x2 layout

Tags: tikz-pgf, groupplots

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes,positioning}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[
  mydot/.style={   circle,   fill,   inner sep=2pt }, >=latex,
                shorten >= 3pt, shorten <= 3pt,
  every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=0pt}
 ]


 \node[mydot,label={left:1}] (a1) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a1,label={left:2}] (a2) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a2,label={left:3}] (a3) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a3,label={left:4}] (a4) {}; 

 \node[mydot,right=4cm of a1,label={right:1}] (b1) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b1,label={right:2}] (b2) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b2,label={right:3}] (b3) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b3,label={right:4}] (b4) {};

 \node[draw,fit=(a1) (a2) (a3) (a4),minimum width=2cm] {} ;
 \node[draw,fit=(b1) (b2) (b3) (b4),minimum width=2cm] {} ;

 \path[->] (a1) edge (b2) edge (b1); 
 \path[->] (a2) edge (b4); 
 \path[->] (a3) edge (b3); 
 \path[<-] (a4) edge (b1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The above MWE generates a mapping diagram.
I am trying to create a 2x2 `groupplot` of the above function mapping diagram.

I have used the `groupplot` environment on previous occasions with great success (when using graphs on a Cartesian plane); via the `\addplot` command.

However, using the Ti*k*Z commands for the function mapping diagrams, all I can generate are 4 boxes with tick marks around them.

Comment: Could you provide a MWE, which include the document class, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I like to use the subfig package inside a figure.

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes,positioning}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{subfig}

 \begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat{
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
  mydot/.style={   circle,   fill,   inner sep=2pt }, >=latex,
                shorten >= 3pt, shorten <= 3pt,
  every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=0pt}
 ]


 \node[mydot,label={left:1}] (a1) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a1,label={left:2}] (a2) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a2,label={left:3}] (a3) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a3,label={left:4}] (a4) {}; 

 \node[mydot,right=4cm of a1,label={right:1}] (b1) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b1,label={right:2}] (b2) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b2,label={right:3}] (b3) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b3,label={right:4}] (b4) {};

 \node[draw,fit=(a1) (a2) (a3) (a4),minimum width=2cm] {} ;
 \node[draw,fit=(b1) (b2) (b3) (b4),minimum width=2cm] {} ;

 \path[->] (a1) edge (b2) edge (b1); 
 \path[->] (a2) edge (b4); 
 \path[->] (a3) edge (b3); 
 \path[<-] (a4) edge (b1);

\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
  mydot/.style={   circle,   fill,   inner sep=2pt }, >=latex,
                shorten >= 3pt, shorten <= 3pt,
  every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=0pt}
 ]


 \node[mydot,label={left:1}] (a1) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a1,label={left:2}] (a2) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a2,label={left:3}] (a3) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a3,label={left:4}] (a4) {}; 

 \node[mydot,right=4cm of a1,label={right:1}] (b1) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b1,label={right:2}] (b2) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b2,label={right:3}] (b3) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b3,label={right:4}] (b4) {};

 \node[draw,fit=(a1) (a2) (a3) (a4),minimum width=2cm] {} ;
 \node[draw,fit=(b1) (b2) (b3) (b4),minimum width=2cm] {} ;

 \path[->] (a1) edge (b2) edge (b1); 
 \path[->] (a2) edge (b4); 
 \path[->] (a3) edge (b3); 
 \path[<-] (a4) edge (b1);

\end{tikzpicture}}

\subfloat{
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
  mydot/.style={   circle,   fill,   inner sep=2pt }, >=latex,
                shorten >= 3pt, shorten <= 3pt,
  every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=0pt}
 ]


 \node[mydot,label={left:1}] (a1) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a1,label={left:2}] (a2) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a2,label={left:3}] (a3) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a3,label={left:4}] (a4) {}; 

 \node[mydot,right=4cm of a1,label={right:1}] (b1) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b1,label={right:2}] (b2) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b2,label={right:3}] (b3) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b3,label={right:4}] (b4) {};

 \node[draw,fit=(a1) (a2) (a3) (a4),minimum width=2cm] {} ;
 \node[draw,fit=(b1) (b2) (b3) (b4),minimum width=2cm] {} ;

 \path[->] (a1) edge (b2) edge (b1); 
 \path[->] (a2) edge (b4); 
 \path[->] (a3) edge (b3); 
 \path[<-] (a4) edge (b1);

\end{tikzpicture}}
\subfloat{
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
  mydot/.style={   circle,   fill,   inner sep=2pt }, >=latex,
                shorten >= 3pt, shorten <= 3pt,
  every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=0pt}
 ]


 \node[mydot,label={left:1}] (a1) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a1,label={left:2}] (a2) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a2,label={left:3}] (a3) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a3,label={left:4}] (a4) {}; 

 \node[mydot,right=4cm of a1,label={right:1}] (b1) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b1,label={right:2}] (b2) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b2,label={right:3}] (b3) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b3,label={right:4}] (b4) {};

 \node[draw,fit=(a1) (a2) (a3) (a4),minimum width=2cm] {} ;
 \node[draw,fit=(b1) (b2) (b3) (b4),minimum width=2cm] {} ;

 \path[->] (a1) edge (b2) edge (b1); 
 \path[->] (a2) edge (b4); 
 \path[->] (a3) edge (b3); 
 \path[<-] (a4) edge (b1);

\end{tikzpicture}}


\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks guys. I am going to add captioning, so I will use the subfig version.

Answer (score 5):

A `tikzpicture` is like a `char`, you can organize them as you want. In this particular case, I've used a `tabular` to place them 2x2.

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes,positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
  mydot/.style={   circle,   fill,   inner sep=2pt }, >=latex,
                shorten >= 3pt, shorten <= 3pt,
  every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=0pt}
 ]


 \node[mydot,label={left:1}] (a1) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a1,label={left:2}] (a2) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a2,label={left:3}] (a3) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a3,label={left:4}] (a4) {}; 

 \node[mydot,right=4cm of a1,label={right:1}] (b1) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b1,label={right:2}] (b2) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b2,label={right:3}] (b3) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b3,label={right:4}] (b4) {};

 \node[draw,fit=(a1) (a2) (a3) (a4),minimum width=2cm] {} ;
 \node[draw,fit=(b1) (b2) (b3) (b4),minimum width=2cm] {} ;

 \path[->] (a1) edge (b2) edge (b1); 
 \path[->] (a2) edge (b4); 
 \path[->] (a3) edge (b3); 
 \path[<-] (a4) edge (b1);

\end{tikzpicture}
&
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
  mydot/.style={   circle,   fill,   inner sep=2pt }, >=latex,
                shorten >= 3pt, shorten <= 3pt,
  every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=0pt}
 ]


 \node[mydot,label={left:1}] (a1) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a1,label={left:2}] (a2) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a2,label={left:3}] (a3) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a3,label={left:4}] (a4) {}; 

 \node[mydot,right=4cm of a1,label={right:1}] (b1) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b1,label={right:2}] (b2) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b2,label={right:3}] (b3) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b3,label={right:4}] (b4) {};

 \node[draw,fit=(a1) (a2) (a3) (a4),minimum width=2cm] {} ;
 \node[draw,fit=(b1) (b2) (b3) (b4),minimum width=2cm] {} ;

 \path[->] (a1) edge (b2) edge (b1); 
 \path[->] (a2) edge (b4); 
 \path[->] (a3) edge (b3); 
 \path[<-] (a4) edge (b1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\\
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
  mydot/.style={   circle,   fill,   inner sep=2pt }, >=latex,
                shorten >= 3pt, shorten <= 3pt,
  every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=0pt}
 ]


 \node[mydot,label={left:1}] (a1) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a1,label={left:2}] (a2) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a2,label={left:3}] (a3) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a3,label={left:4}] (a4) {}; 

 \node[mydot,right=4cm of a1,label={right:1}] (b1) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b1,label={right:2}] (b2) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b2,label={right:3}] (b3) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b3,label={right:4}] (b4) {};

 \node[draw,fit=(a1) (a2) (a3) (a4),minimum width=2cm] {} ;
 \node[draw,fit=(b1) (b2) (b3) (b4),minimum width=2cm] {} ;

 \path[->] (a1) edge (b2) edge (b1); 
 \path[->] (a2) edge (b4); 
 \path[->] (a3) edge (b3); 
 \path[<-] (a4) edge (b1);

\end{tikzpicture}
&
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
  mydot/.style={   circle,   fill,   inner sep=2pt }, >=latex,
                shorten >= 3pt, shorten <= 3pt,
  every fit/.style={ellipse,draw,inner sep=0pt}
 ]


 \node[mydot,label={left:1}] (a1) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a1,label={left:2}] (a2) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a2,label={left:3}] (a3) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of a3,label={left:4}] (a4) {}; 

 \node[mydot,right=4cm of a1,label={right:1}] (b1) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b1,label={right:2}] (b2) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b2,label={right:3}] (b3) {};  
 \node[mydot,below=of b3,label={right:4}] (b4) {};

 \node[draw,fit=(a1) (a2) (a3) (a4),minimum width=2cm] {} ;
 \node[draw,fit=(b1) (b2) (b3) (b4),minimum width=2cm] {} ;

 \path[->] (a1) edge (b2) edge (b1); 
 \path[->] (a2) edge (b4); 
 \path[->] (a3) edge (b3); 
 \path[<-] (a4) edge (b1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]